# Kohana MVC framework ORM schema force update database

Tags: php, model-view-controller, orm, kohana

I've inherited a kohana project.  It uses ORM, I've have it locally.

I wondered if anyone knew, if there is a way of creating a database from the ORM structure?  Bit like `app/console doctrine:schema:update --force` in Symfony to save having to pick through and create the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long I am aware of Kohana framework ORM it creates Objects from DB tables but does not stores table schema in ORM classes. You can go thought Modules as some modules have SQL schema as *.sql file you can use that to install that portion. It depends on each Module